# Issue while loading android emulator

Tags: android

I have this issue frequently appearing while running the android emulator. It tries to load the emulator and after this message

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

The emulator kind of gets stuck, it doesn't install my application and just loads. I have to normally close eclipse and start it again to make it work again. What is the reason behind this and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the adb and then start loading the emulator.

Comment: what do you mean by reset adb

Comment: Unless this is installation problem,if you want to restore the emulator to its original state (to reset it, that is), simply delete the userdata-qemu.img file located at C:\Users\...\.android\avd\Android_2.2_Emulator.avd[here ... means username folder and emulator can be different] OR simply delete current avd and create new one.Hope this can solve problem